# Object comparison Complexity Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, time-complexity, equality

I would like to compare the performances of comparing two objects in JavaScript having a unique id 'key' using their key or equality sign i.e: `object1 === object2` or `object1.key === object2.key`.

While both are working I am wondering is it better to compare directly the keys as it will have only two values to compare or is Javascipt comparing each key / value in each value and then the complexity would be `O(n)` (n being the muber of keys of an object)

Is it comparing addresses or something to make it efficient?

Comment: Are there distinct objects with the same `.key`? Then your first version won't work, objects are compared by their identity ("address") and not by their contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1. comparing distinct objects:

> While both are working

Well they don't :

```
{a: 1} == {a: 1} // false
```

you can't compare two distinct objects by two (or three) equal sign. you have two way:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 1}) === JSON.stringify({a: 1})
```

Or:

```
{key: 1, a: 1}.key === {key: 1, a: 1}.key
```

Which obviously the second one is more efficient.

---

Case 2. Comparing non-distinct objects like:

```
var obj1 = {key: 1, a: 1, b: 2}
var obj2 = {key: 2, a: 1, b: 2}
var obj3 = obj1
obj3 === obj1 // true
```

There is no difference between comparing them directly or comparing them by your keys, both are O(1) since js will compare them by refrence, not by comparing their key-values.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer